# How to open .csv file from a url with Python?

Tags: python, url, csv

I'm trying to open a csv file from a url but for some reason I get an error saying that there is an invalid mode or filename. I'm not sure what the issue is. Help?

```
url = "http://...."
data = open(url, "r")
read = csv.DictReader(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the stream, then process:

```
import urllib2
url = "http://httpbin.org/get"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = response.read()
read = csv.DictReader(data)
```

Comment: Thanks @Esparta Palma for the answer. It helped me. Here's the version that worked for me:

''''
import urllib2
url = "http://httpbin.org/get"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = response.read().decode('utf-8')
read = csv.DictReader(data.splitlines())
for row in read:
    # Do something
''''

Answer (score 2):

I recommend pandas for this:

```
import pandas as pd
read = pandas.io.parsers.read_csv("http://....", ...)
```

please see the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html).

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the standard urllib to download from the URL and parse the stream.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following :

```
import csv
import urllib2

url = 'http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
cr = csv.reader(response)

for row in cr:
 print row
```

Answer (score -2):

Slightly tongue in cheek:

```
require json
>>> for line in file(','):
...     print json.loads('['+line+']')
```

CSV is not a well defined format.  JSON is so this will parse a certain type of CSV correctly every time.